# Finding posts containing matching array elements in a meta field usign WP_Query

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, wp-query, loop

I have a metafield, that contains a series of options and writes the results to an array in a single meta field:

```
array([0]=>'First',
      [1]=>'Second',
      [2]=>'Third',
     );
```

I find posts that contain any of the array elements, and display them using `WP_Query`

```
$search = new WP_Query('meta_key=mykey&meta_value=second');
```

But this doesn't seem to work. Any idea on how to achieve this?

---

I have edited my method, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095954/select-based-on-item-within-an-array/7096348#7096348) question:

```
$arg['meta_key'] == $key;
$args['meta_value'] = "%|".$value."|%";
$custom_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

But no darts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to use meta compare LIKE. If you do a regular meta query, the resulting SQL will be meta_value = your_value, which is never going to find anything because it's trying to match the entire contents of the field.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure to return or search an array for values (or keys) you need to use `meta_query`

So something like:

```
$search = array(
           'post_type' => 'post',
           'meta_query' => array(
                                array(
                                   'key'     => 'mykey',
                                   'value'   => 'second',
                                     )
                                )
                );

 $query = new WP_Query($search);
```

Comment: No joy I am afraid.